# AngularJS : How can we broadcast promise to different controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

How can we broadcast updated data from factory.
Am having two factories and two controllers.

Service1: updates the data into db

```
app.factory('uac',function($http,$q, $cookies)
{
   formData.uClient = function(data)
   {
      var client = $http.post('add_client/',data)
      return $q.all({'response':client})
   }
}
```

service 2: gets list of clients from db

```
app.factory('adService',function($http, $q)
{
   clientData = {}
   clientData.getListofClients = function()
   {
       var listOfClients = $http.get('get_clients/')
       return $q.all({'listOfClients':listOfClients})
   }
   return clientData
})
```

controller 1: sends data to be updated to service

```
app.controller('acController', function($scope,uac)
{
    $scope.clientDatadata = {name:"abcd"}
    uac.uClient($scope.clientData)
}
```

controller 2: gets clients data from service

```
app.controller('getDetailsController',function($scope,adService)
{
   adService.getListofClients().then(function(data)
   {
      $scope.clientList = data.listOfClients.data
      console.log($scope.clientList)
   },
   function(error)
   {
      console.log("Can fetch data")
   });
}
```

First I will call getDetailsController to get all clients and whenever a new client is added by calling "acController" i want the updated list of clients in "$scope.clientList".How can i get it done?

Comment: what are you returning on the uClient? Is that the full list of clients, same as on the adService.getListofClients method?

Answer (score 2):

You can [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) on event from the sender controller and listen for it in the receiver controller. Since I'm not sure about the hierarchy of your controllers, I'll listen on $rootScope:

controller 1: sends data to be updated to service

```
app.controller('acController', function($scope,uac)
{
    $scope.clientDatadata = {name:"abcd"}
    uac.uClient($scope.clientData).then(function(res){
        $scope.$emit('serviceUpdated', res); // you can send data if you wish
    });
}
```

controller 2: gets clients data from service

```
app.controller('getDetailsController',function($scope,adService,$rootScope)
{
   function getList(){
       adService.getListofClients().then(function(data)
       {
           $scope.clientList = data.listOfClients.data
           console.log($scope.clientList)
       },
       function(error)
       {
           console.log("Can fetch data")
       });
    }

    getList();
    $rootScope.$on('serviceUpdated', getList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to go for this:

1. (easy) Create a factory which will contain the list of clients and use it directly on your view.

-

```
myApp.factory('clientList', function () {
    return [];
});
```

call controller 2 to get the list of clients and save on the factory:

```
app.controller('getDetailsController',function($scope,adService, clientList)
{
   adService.getListofClients().then(function(data)
   {
        clientList = data;
   },
   function(error)
   {
      console.log("Can fetch data");
   });
}
```

controller 1: sends data to be updated to service and saves the returned data on the clientList factory

```
app.controller('acController', function($scope,uac, clientList)
{
    $scope.clientDatadata = {name:"abcd"};
    clientList = uac.uClient($scope.clientData);
}
```

The issue about this solution is that in a complex app you wouldn't want to have the data exposed via a factory.

2. Implement getters and setters on the factory so you don't expose the data to the views but rather have them controlled by the controllers (using [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)).
3. Use [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) as explained on the answer by @Shomz. But, I would propose to make another get list request after the emission is received. I'd rather broadcast the updated data(in this case the response of the post/update request) and than update the variables that are bound to views.